# How to allow different ports in google cloud ?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I create one instance on google cloud. Now I want to enable port 9001 and port 7474. I have created a firewall using these ports but still it is not working,  this is my firewall:

```
allow-neo4j-supervisor

Network

default
Priority

1000
Direction

Ingress
Action on match

Allow
Source filters

IP ranges
0.0.0.0
Protocols and ports

tcp:9001
tcp:7474
```

Do I also need to change any other setting ?

Answer (score 0):

No offense, but you might want to make sure that you are using the external IP address when connecting to your instance. This stuff happens all the time.

Comment: I am using external IP i.e. why without 7474 it is working but with 7474 it is not.